# How to create a heightmap using intel realsense d435

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, heightmap, realsense

Sorry for my bad english and also i am new hew here.

I have a intel d435 depth camera and a raspberry pi and a diy rc style car which i run using the raspberry pi onboard. I have put aruco markers at specific places in my room.Using these and a webcam onboard i got a position feedback.I wrote a script to make the car go to desired location using the aruco markers using pre defined position of marker's data. So making the car go from a to b is not an issue(it goes along a straight line).

But now i want it to go from point a to b avoding static obstacles.

I just learned about Astar alogorithm.
As far as i understand, it is possible to plot a path from a definite start point to a definite end point(Generally speaking).

So i want to use my intel d435 camera to generate a  heightmap of my room and plot it using 3d scatter plot using matplotlib .I think it is possible since the d435 can output point cloud data.But i have very poor programming skills and cant find any example that shows some thing similar.
Then may plan is get to a frame, get the height data from a 3d array, run A*, choose the desired node and drive the car until it gets there and repeat until destination is reached.

So to summarize my question is how to plot point cloud from the intel d435 without texture using a 3d array and scatter plot function of matplotlib.

```py
import cv2                                
import numpy as np                       
import pyrealsense2 as rs
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt          
import time
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig1 = plt.figure(1)
ar = fig1.gca(projection='3d')
ar.set_xlim(-1, 1)
ar.set_ylim(-1, 1)
ar.set_zlim(-1, 1)


# Configure depth and color streams
pipeline = rs.pipeline()
config = rs.config()
config.enable_stream(rs.stream.depth, 640, 480, rs.format.z16, 30)
config.enable_stream(rs.stream.color, 640, 480, rs.format.bgr8, 30)


# Start streaming
pipe_profile =pipeline.start(config)

points =[[[]]]
def get_3dPoints():#Function to be written
    pass    

try:
    while True:
        # Wait for a coherent pair of frames: depth and color
        frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames()
        depth_frame = frames.get_depth_frame()
        color_frame = frames.get_color_frame()

        if not depth_frame or not color_frame: #or not infrared_frame:
            continue
        # Convert images to numpy arrays
        depth_image = np.asanyarray(depth_frame.get_data())
        color_image = np.asanyarray(color_frame.get_data())

        cv2.namedWindow('RealSense', cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
        colorizer = rs.colorizer()
        depth_colormap = np.asanyarray(colorizer.colorize(depth_frame).get_data())
        cv2.imshow('RealSense', depth_colormap)
        """
        points = get_3dPoints()
        tgt = ar.scatter(points, 'red')
        ar.set_xlabel('X - axis')
        ar.set_ylabel('Y - axis')
        ar.set_zlabel('Z - axis')
        plt.pause(0.00000000000000001)
        tgt.remove()
        """
        cv2.waitKey(1)

finally:

    # Stop streaming#img = cv2.resize(img, (1280, 720), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    pipeline.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this repo regarding how to get a heatmap [link](https://github.com/varchanaiyer/realsense)

There are also a lot of resources in the official Intel repo [here](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/tree/master/wrappers/python/examples)

Comment: IN These examples, the xyz plots are like this(pixel_x,pixel_y,depth) but i need the points in ths format-(x,y,z) where xyz are the real co-ordinate a point in 3d space with respects to the camera's reference frame.